# Native proxies does not appear in application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have created eclipse application using eclipse photon. I can see the native proxies in eclipse but i cannot see them in the application I have created.

Is there any extensions that needs to be added to make the native proxies appear in my application

**Edit:**
The below image contains the native proxy appearing in eclipse

[image: Native Proxy]
The same does not appear in my application

Comment: What are 'native proxies' in this context?

Comment: @greg Sorry for the explanation. When we click on window -> prefences -> network connections, we get a list of items. We have three options native, direct and manual. When we click on native, the native ones get selected. The ones we have defined in our machine.  In my case Only the default ones are present in the list. The native ones does not appear in my application

Comment: @greg-449 I have edited my original post with image for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class called `org.eclipse.core.net.ProxyProvider` provides the native providers - this is loaded using `Class.forName` by `org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyManager`.

It looks like this class is provided by a platform specific plug-in fragment, for example `org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_64` on Linux. So make sure you are including the appropriate fragment in your build.